# Space stations is there 3

Tags: artificial-satellite

Are there 3 space stations, one in the west low one in the south about 30 ' at about 10pmUK skies , and the Chinese coming over from SE th SW in day brake at 4am

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking here. Could you edit your question to make it easier for other users to answer?

Comment: You can check what satellites you have seen at the site https://www.heavens-above.com

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 space stations: the ISS and the Chinese Tiangong-2. The third object could have been a satellite: there are plenty of bright ones.

Comment: Tend to dis agree as I have clear skies

Comment: @JimHood: How do you tell these apart?

Comment: The two I see at night about 10 just before dark are in the sky at the same time , one in thee West low one in the south about 45' . The other I believe to be the Chinese rises in the east and goes a cross the south sky at about 3 am glowing red. They are to bright for satalites